# Why acts std::chrono::duration::operator*= not like built-in *=?

Tags: c++, c++11, duration

As described in [std::chrono::duration::operator+=](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration/operator_arith3) the signature is

```
duration& operator*=(const rep& rhs);
```

This makes me wonder. I would assume that a duration literal can be used like any other built-in, but it doesn't.

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    using namespace std::chrono_literals;
    auto m = 10min;
    m *= 1.5f;
    std::cout << " 150% of 10min: " << m.count() << "min" << std::endl;

    int i = 10;
    i *= 1.5f;
    std::cout << " 150% of 10: " << i << std::endl;
}
```

Output is

```
150% of 10min: 10min
150% of 10: 15
```

Why was the interface choosen that way? To my mind, an interface like

```
template<typename T> 
duration& operator*=(const T& rhs);
```

would yield more intuitive results.

**EDIT:**
Thanks for your responses, I know that the implementation behaves that way and how I could handle it. My question is, *why* is it designed that way.

I would expect the conversion to int take place at the end of the operation. In the following example both operands get promoted to double before the multiplications happens. The intermediate result of 4.5 is converted to int afterwards, so that the result is 4.

```
int i = 3;
i *= 1.5;
assert(i == 4);
```

My expectation for `std::duration` would be that it behaves the same way.

Comment: rep is  `an arithmetic type representing the number of ticks`, and is `/*signed integer type of at least 29 bits*/` for minutes, not `float`.

Comment: `POD` is not the right term here. You probably meant "built in".

Comment: Besides the terminology I 100% agree that a `template <class T> duration& operator*=(const T& rhs);` version would be more intuitive. As e.g. `int i = 10; i *= 1.5;` also results in `i == 15`, I'm wondering why the C++ dogma of "custom types should be usable like built in ones" is not followed here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> My question is, why is it designed that way.

It was designed this way (ironically) because the integral-based computations are designed to give exact results, or not compile.  However in this case the `<chrono>` library exerts no control over what conversions get applied to arguments *prior* to binding to the arguments.

As a concrete example, consider the case where `m` is initialized to `11min`, and presume that we had a templated `operator*=` as you suggest.  The *exact* answer is now `16.5min`, but the integral-based type `chrono::minutes` is not capable of representing this value.

A superior design would be to have this line:

```
m *= 1.5f;  // compile-time error
```

not compile.  That would make the library more self-consistent:  Integral-based arithmetic is either exact (or requires `duration_cast`) or does not compile.  This would be possible to implement, and the answer as to why this was not done is simply that I didn't think of it.

---

If you (or anyone else) feels strongly enough about this to try to standardize a compile-time error for the above statement, I would be willing to speak in favor of such a proposal in committee.

This effort would involve:

- An implementation with unit tests.
- Fielding it to get a feel for how much code it would break, and ensuring that it does not break code not intended.
- Write a paper and submit it to the C++ committee, targeting C++23 (it is too late to target C++20).

The easiest way to do this would be to start with an open-source implementation such as gcc's libstdc++ or llvm's libc++.

Comment: How is "Integral-based arithmetic is either exact (or requires duration_cast) or does not compile." (more) consistent with the built-in example I provided above, which complies and which isn't exact? Wouldn't a compile error just provide another kind of inconsistency?
(I will take it into consideration to write a proposal. I'm new to the process, so it may take some time to get familiar with the process. :-) )

Comment: I changed "consistent" to "self-consistent" in my answer.  I.e. this change would make the library more consistent with itself.  In other arithmetic expressions, the result of integral and floating-point mixed expressions result in a floating-point based result.  And in the chrono library, floating point based types won't convert to integral based types without an explicit named conversion (e.g. `duration_cast` or `time_point_cast`, and in C++17, `floor`, `ceil` and `round`).

Comment: @MichaelReinhardt 10min * 1 is exactly 10min. The loss of precision happens before the call to the operator so as to satisfy the signature. This is, for historical reasons / inherited from C), and outside of chrono's control. Yes, as H.H. stated, it could be fixed (or worked around), e.g. by adding overloads that are `= deleted`, but IMO C and C++ should just finally deprecate potentially lossy implicit conversions with the intent to remove them. Yes, there would be another epic rant by Linus Torvalds on how much language committees suck, but in the end the community should be better off.

Answer (score 11):

The issue here is

```
auto m = 10min;
```

gives you a `std::chrono::duration` where `rep` is a signed integer type.  When you do

```
m *= 1.5f;
```

the `1.5f` is converted to the type `rep` and that means it is truncated to `1`, which gives you the same value after multiplication.

To fix this you need to use

```
auto m = 10.0min;
```

to get a `std::chrono::duration` that uses a floating point type for `rep` and wont truncate `1.5f` when you do `m *= 1.5f;`.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the implementation of `operator*=`:

```
_CONSTEXPR17 duration& operator*=(const _Rep& _Right)
    {   // multiply rep by _Right
    _MyRep *= _Right;
    return (*this);
    }
```

the operator takes a `const _Rep&`. It comes from `std::duration` which looks like:

```
template<class _Rep, //<-
    class _Period>
    class duration
    {   // represents a time Duration
    //...
```

So now if we look at the definition of `std::chrono::minutes`:

```
using minutes = duration<int, ratio<60>>;
```

It is clear that **`_Rep` is an `int`**.

---

So when you call `operator*=(const _Rep& _Right)` `1.5f` is beeing cast to an `int` - which equals `1` and therefore won't affect any mulitiplications with itself.

***So what can you do?***

you can split it up into `m = m * 1.5f` and use `std::chrono::duration_cast` to cast from `std::chrono::duration<float, std::ratio>` to `std::chrono::duration<int, std::ratio>`

```
m = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::minutes>(m * 1.5f);
```

> 150% of 10min: 15min

---

if you don't like always casting it, use a `float` for it as the first template argument:

```
std::chrono::duration<float, std::ratio<60>> m = 10min;
m *= 1.5f; //> 15min
```

or even quicker - `auto m = 10.0min; m *= 1.5f;` as @NathanOliver answered :-)